# sending value inside <options> tag through url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hey guys I'm using the Laravel framework. I fetched data from my database and populated my drop down list like this.

```
<select class="form-control" id="username" name="username">     
                <option value="" selected>Select User</option>
                @foreach($getUsers as $list)
                <option value="{{$list->id}}" >{{$list->name}}</option>
                @endforeach

            </select>
```

I want to be able to click one of the options in the drop down list and send the value through a url (preferably using href) and reload the page.

Comment: so use $_GET and create form

Comment: Do you have your `select` element in a form? That's exactly how forms work.

Comment: Do you need an ajax on each option select ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple javascript function bound to the `onchange` event of the select menu like this.

```
<script>
    function offyoupop(e){
        location.search='username='+e.target.value;
    }
</script>

<select name='username' id='username' class='form-control' onchange='offyoupop(event)'>
    <option>Please select
    <option value='1'>One
    <option value='2'>Two
    <option value='3'>Three
    <option value='4'>Four
    <option value='5'>Five
</select>
```

Comment: I can't pass the value to offyoupop(event) because it is in a loop

Comment: what is `in a loop`?

Comment: the <option> tag with the value attribute is in the forreach loop

Comment: I don't see the problem. The `onchange` event handler is assigned to the `select` element - when it changes the javascript function obtains the selected value. Have I missed something?